# How to make item active by default and remove after click on other items in Angular?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have this:

```
  <a class="button" ng-click="$parent.Filter = ''" 
     ng-class="{ 'active': Filter === '' }"> Test link </a>
```

And the next item:

```
<a class="button" ng-click="$parent.Filter = 'SomeChoice'" 
   ng-class="{ 'active': Filter === 'SomeChoice' }"> </a>
```

So, as you can see... these are filters.

What I want to achieve? When I get in the controller where this `HTML` is, I want the first link to have the *ACTIVE* class by **default**..

And, after I click on the second link, I want that active class to be **removed** from the first **and added to the second** one...

My question: how do I achieve this in `Angular`?

**Plunkr:** https://plnkr.co/edit/n9faIH2YZzIj8vOncfLP?p=preview

PS: the classes and filters I use, have to remain the same.

Comment: Can you create a plunker for your question?

Comment: Yes, there you: https://plnkr.co/edit/n9faIH2YZzIj8vOncfLP?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div ng-init="active = 1">
<a ng-click="active = 1" ng-class="{'active': active === 1}">1</a>
<a ng-click="active = 2" ng-class="{'active': active === 2}">2</a>
<a ng-click="active = 3" ng-class="{'active': active === 3}">3</a>
</div>
```

Working plnkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/wnRynCG0IcKLJcVk4xMw?p=preview

Comment: Isn't there a better way to do this?

Comment: you can move the logic to the controller and make it more dynamic but at the end it's a very small thing the one you want  to accompish.

Comment: The problem with your solution, is that you ignore my own filters and classes. I have put them there for a reason... can I combine them? If so, how? If not, then it's not an answer...

Comment: @Siyah up to you to adapt the code not to me sorry, this example works perfectly. For sure you can add filters and more